# "critical" nominalization

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, nominalizations

I'm looking for the nominalization of the adjective "critical". Basically, a noun synonymous with the following:

> The extent to which a particular issue or item is critical or vital

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: 'Critical' being an extreme adjective, 'a particular issue or item' is critical/vital ... or ... not. While 'criticality' means  'the state of being critical', it wouldn't make sense to have a noun meaning 'the extent of criticality' (or 'the extent of an animal's deadness'). One could have 'closeness to being vital', which is usually called 'importance'.

Answer (score 1):

criticality
1. The state of being critical
(Wiktionary)

Answer (score 0):

*Pertinence* means importance in a specific situation. While it doesn't convey the need for urgency, it weeds out the unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, "urgency" may be a good term to use here, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to "criticality" might be "**necessity**", as in "[The Necessity of Art](http://www.counterfire.org/articles/book-reviews/6012-ernst-fischer-the-necessity-of-art-a-marxist-approach)" and "[The Necessity of Errors](http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/books/the-necessity-of-errors/418918.article)".